# Oracle to MySQL timestamp conversion in MySQL insert statement

Tags: mysql, oracle, format, timestamp, database-migration

I've already exported data from an Oracle 11g instance as insert statements. They need to go into a MySQL 5.5 instance. Having trouble with the `TIMESTAMP` conversion; I know I can use the `TO_TIMESTAMP` function inline with `INSERT` statements in MySQL; however, am unsure as to the correct flags to use. As follows below, in linear order, is: the Oracle timestamp statement and my attempt at a MySQL compatible statement. Obviously it's not working (in that MySQL states there's a syntax error).

Oracle:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('12/22/2015 5:08:59.245837 PM','fmMMfm/fmDDfm/YYYY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM')
```

MySQL:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('12/22/2015 5:08:59.245837 PM','%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s')
```

What am I missing beyond flags for microseconds and AM/PM?

Comment: I'm not seeing a `TO_TIMESTAMP` function in MySQL 5.5 docs. I think you want something like `STR_TO_DATE` instead.

Answer (score 1):

FOR MYSQL:
STR_TO_DATE('2/6/2015 5:20:43.000000 AM','%c/%d/%Y %l:%i:%s.%f %p')

Answer (score 0):

assumed you export from SQL Developer.

before you export the whole data, change your datetime select query with :

```
TO_CHAR(COLUMN_NAME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as XXX
```

it will produce datetime with MySQL format. so when you get the insert query, you can run directly at MySQL

Answer (score 0):

if you want the date and the timestamp of oracle to be compatible with MySql just alter you session

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF'
```

it is better to alter session