# How to convert timestamp from Oracle to Mysql

Tags: mysql, unix, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to convert timestamp from Oracle to Mysql. I have a data text file, trying to load data in MySQL database but getting an SQL syntax error. Please help

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/check/value.txt' INTO TABLE TEST FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' (ID, @DATETIME) SET DATETIME = CONVERT_TZ(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@DATETIME, '-', 3),"T"," "), "-07:00", "+00:00");
```

timestamp example - 2020-10-07T05:21:05-7:00.

Below is the error

```
 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET DATETIME = CONVERT_TZ(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@DATETIME, '-', 3),"T"," "), "-07:00", "+00:00")'
```

Comment: Try to refer following link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125393/oracle-to-mysql-timestamp-conversion-in-mysql-insert-statement

Comment: @CDN In my case input format is different, It's not working for me

Comment: 1) MySQL treates `@time` as user-defined variable. Does it has shown value? 2) The value contains excess `T` and `-7:00` which are not mentioned in the pattern. 3) MySQL cannot use timezone info by this way (in datetime literal), it operates only with clear datetime without timezone. 4) `time` in `Set time` is treated as local variable which is not legal out of compound statement. *getting an SQL syntax error* We do not see error message text...

Comment: Your `LOAD DATA` statement is synthactically incorrect. If `DATETIME` is a column name in `TEST` table structure than you MUST wrap it with backticks because `DATETIME` is reserved word.

Comment: @Akina I have changed the column name from 'DATETIME' to 'LASTTIME'  and change the LOAD query as required but getting the same error

Comment: Must work. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceNh5.png Search the problem elsewhere.

Comment: @Akina; thanks for putting the complete solution. I like the question and answer !

Comment: @Akina Can you please tell me your MySQL version, still it showing the same error for me.

Comment: @Ankina from the SS I'm seeing that your MySQL version is 8.0.16 but in my case version is 8.0.17 so, is this problem happening for a different version?

Comment: @SanjoyDey No, the code must work on all versions from 5.6 (at least) till the most recent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX("2020-10-07T05:21:05-7:00", '-', 3),"T"," "), "-07:00", "+00:00");
```

Comment: @Sanjoy: this is a workaround solution. please let me know if it works for you !

Comment: In general the timezone shift may be positive too - in such case your query will fail. And it is more correct to retrieve timezone shift from the literal.

Comment: @Akina; I agree with you. In that case OP has to keep conditions for positive and negative value in timezone. I have given a solution, how to convert from Oracle to MySQL conversation format (workaround) !

Comment: @SKM it's not working for me, getting the same syntax error

Comment: Solution link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c9c315bc69b7ac6020adc22ae958c804

Comment: @SanjoyDey *it's not working for me, getting the same syntax error* WHAT "the same"??? where is complete error message?

Comment: @SKM I have sample values as a text file, already given an example of the value in the question and passes those value through the Load Data Infile query in the MySQL database dynamically, I need to store only date and time from the sample value, timezone is not required for me in mysql database

Comment: Hope this will help: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e4d6716e823231ce921081205c818f3e

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET time = CONVERT_TZ(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_NDEX(@time, '-', 3),"T"," "), "-07:00", "+00:00")

Comment: SET @time = CONVERT_TZ(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@time, '-', 3),"T"," "), "-07:00", "+00:00");

Comment: @SanjoyDey MySQL tells that SET not allowed in this place. Edit your question text, add the error message into it. And show FULL code, not one line of it.

Comment: @Akina SET is allowed in MySQL syntax, I have another LOAD query where SET is working fine.

Comment: @SanjoyDey :facepalm: Do you understand that each keyword has a list of places where it can be used, and another list of places where it cannot be used? Keyword existence does not match that it can be applied anywhere...

Comment: @Akina According to your advise I have edited my question, please check

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SET @time := '2020-10-07T05:21:05-7:00';
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(STR_TO_DATE( @time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s'),            -- datetime only
                  REGEXP_SUBSTR(@time, '[\+\-][0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}$'),  -- timeshift only
                  '+00:00') AS datetime_GMT;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=483fe68cb65cac0875eb732c3d4dd868)

Comment: Looks like, my solution is not useful. shall I delete my post ?

Comment: @SKM I do not see the reason. Additionally - your answer delete will delete all its comments which is good hardly.